# Excel's cell center shifted

Tags: excel, fractions, vba

I have been working on a math drill program for a bit now. I had asked a similar question to this previously but I wasn't getting any good help with it. So I decided to research the problem more thoroughly and found something interesting.

Now before I begin, I just want to go over the preliminaries. Yes, I am using Microsoft Excel 2007. No, while this may work for you, it is not for me.

Okay now that, that is taken care of:

The problem I am having is when I have

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "# ?/?"
```

in my my code it causes the excel's center line to be shifted to the left (that is the only way i know how to explain it).

Meaning, if you have something right justified, it will look centered, if it is centered it will be almost left justified and there is very little difference between left and center justified.

if i have

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "?/?"
```

then there is none of the above problems.

The entire code of this section is as follows:

```
Sub test()
  Sheets("sheet1").Select
  Range("a1").Select
  For i = 1 To 10
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "# ?/?"
    With ActiveCell
        .Locked = False
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    End With
    ActiveCell.Value = 33
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
  Next i
End Sub
```

Any suggestion or reason for why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. Ideally the user should be able to see a mixed number.

Further information, if I change each cell by hand to fraction then it works fine. it is only when excel does it.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT (2)**

I tried it with Excel 2007 too, and it makes no difference if I change the NumberFormat by hand or by script.

Anyway, the following script should do what you want. Add it to your Worksheet's source.

It is triggered whenever a value is changed. Then it checks if the correct column is affected (1 in my case), and then it tries to format the number with fractions, but if no fractions result from that, it uses a no-fraction-format.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If cell.Column = 1 Then
            If IsNumeric(cell.value) Then
                cell.NumberFormat = "# ?/?"
                cell.Calculate
                If InStr(1, cell.Text, "/") = 0 Then
                    cell.NumberFormat = "#"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

**Original post**

I've only tried it with Excel 2003, but here is no difference between setting it by hand or via VBA. Please make sure that your code does exactly the same that you do manually, just record a macro of what you do manually and run that on another cell.

The reason for the shift is that Excel reserves that space for the fractions.

```
 1,2 -> |      1 1/5|
 1   -> |      1    |
33   -> |     33    |
33,5 -> |     33 1/2|
```

Is the following what you would like to have?

```
 1,2 -> |      1 1/5|
 1   -> |          1|
33   -> |         33|
33,5 -> |     33 1/2|
```

Why would you like it in that format?

Comment: thank you, yes I would like to turn off this reserving space, so that they can just be centered in the column.

I found out the code to change the cells to fractional format from a macro :)

Comment: @Peter Lang: I think you're on the right track with your edited post.  However, it doens't work correctly for decimals that result in 0/X as a remainder, such as 8.05.  To do this correctly, I almost think you need to have a custom function to handle it, but the whole thing is rather nasty.  I think this begs the question as to why you would want to turn off the reserved space in the first place.

Comment: @Ben McCormack: Thanks, did not think of that! I changed it again, now that case is handled too. I still don't know why one would want to turn off the reserved space :)

Comment: I was wanting to disable the reserved space so that a fraction or integer could share the same cell, both under the "fraction" number format and be in the true center of the cell.

Comment: Just to make sure it did it right, I added your code under sheet1 in the vba. if that is right, then the code didn't work for me :(

Comment: update: the if the number has a fractional portion "33 1/2" then it is centered, but if it is just an integer then it is not.

Comment: Does column 'A' contain your values? If not, change cell.Column = 1. Else I'd like you to add the following before End Sub: 'MsgBox "Test"' (without single quotes). This should produce a message box whenever you change a value on your sheet and would help with debugging.

Comment: @Saumel: Anything left we can do for you? You could consider accepting this answer otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It is aligning the number so that the fractional parts are aligned when viewed in columns with a fixed width font.

```
3 1/3
2    
1 3/4
3 2/7
2 2/3
3 1/2
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually a conditional format would work much better to center everything. See the image below for my setup.

[image: Fraction Format Rule]

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting is the way to go to center or right align fractions in Excel, at least for me. This is what I've done:

1 highlight the cells you want to have aligned

2 select "Conditional Formatting" in the Home tab

3 go to "New Rule"

4 Select "Format only cells that contain"

5 select "Specific Text" in the dropdown

6 leave the next box as "Containing"

7 put a . (period) in the text box (This will make excel search for the decimal point in any number)

8 click the "Format" button

9 select "Fraction"

10 click ok

11 if you haven't already right-aligned (or centered) your cells, do it now. (Align buttons are in the home tab.)

Magic!